# How do I handle Angular UI TinyMCE output

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs, tinymce

I have an app frontend in AngularJS, all the content send to servre via JSON request.
The app have an feature that need to use an WYSIWYG editor, so I choose ui-tinymce directive. Everything work fine until I want to display the HTML content return form server:

```
{
  Content: "\n\n\u003ctable\u003e\n\u003ctbody\u003e\n\u003ctr\u003e\n\u003ctd\u003ea\u003c/td\u003e\n\u003ctd\u003ebbb\u003c/td\u003e\n\u003c/tr\u003e\n\u003ctr\u003e\n\u003ctd\u003eaaa\u003c/td\u003e\n\u003ctd\u003ec\u003c/td\u003e\n\u003c/tr\u003e\n\u003c/tbody\u003e\n\u003c/table\u003e"
}
```

The HTML string encoded to that form.
I'm not sure that JSON auto encode these string or AngularJS or TinyMCE, do you know anyway that I can display that string as HTML table by AngularJS (or normal javascript is OK).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, now I know that:

```
"\u003ctable\u003e" == "<table>"
```

and I need to include "ngSanitize" module to my app then I can use "ng-bind-html" to display the HTML string.